# how to evalulate when reading and processing a html/php file

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to create a template function:

```
function includeAndTemplate($file){
    $json = '{"FIRST_NAME" : "First Name", "MIDDLE_NAME" : "Middle Name"}';
    $template_vars = json_decode($json);
    $file = file_get_contents($file);
    foreach($template_vars as $var => $value){
        $file = str_replace("{{\$".$var."}}", $value, $file);
    }   
    return $file;
}
```

My html/php:

```
<p>{{$FIRST_NAME}}, {{$MIDDLE_NAME}}</p>
```

and this works fine.

Now what happens if I have this:

```
<p>{{$FIRST_NAME}}, {{$MIDDLE_NAME}}, the time now is <?php echo data("H:i:s"); ?></p>
```

the raw php code is outputed to the client

Comment: "I get the php echo in browser." well... yeah... isn't that what you want?

Comment: no, I mean the raw code is outputed

Comment: I think he's using a template engine. Because it's expecting `{{ code }}` and he's giving `<?php <code> ?>` it's just repeating the php string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
<?php
function includeAndTemplate($file){
    $json = '{"FIRST_NAME" : "First Name", "MIDDLE_NAME" : "Middle Name"}';
    $template_vars = json_decode($json);

    ob_start();
    require $file;
    $file = ob_get_clean();

    foreach($template_vars as $var => $value){
        $file = str_replace("{{\$".$var."}}", $value, $file);
    }   
    return $file;
}
```

Just include the file so that PHP code is executed and after that replace whatever you want ro replace.

Comment: Great, this works, I can't believe I did not think of this my self.